# ANTLR used for code generation does not match the current runtime version - Apache Spark - Docker File

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

WORKDIR /spark

EXPOSE 10000

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps

RUN curl "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz" --output spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
RUN tar -xf spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
RUN rm spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz

WORKDIR "/spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin"

COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

I want it to run spark.
when I'm trying to access this container I'm getting the following error:

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.7 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.8ANTLR Tool version 4.7 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.8
```

I tried multiple spark versions and got the same error (with different ANTLR versions).

this is what I see in the initialization of the container:

```
2024-03-14 21:44:34 :: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
2024-03-14 21:44:34 Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
2024-03-14 21:44:34 The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
2024-03-14 21:44:34 io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
2024-03-14 21:44:34 :: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-15c16a62-a3ce-42e7-815c-2fba037cd4c3;1.0
2024-03-14 21:44:34 confs: [default]
2024-03-14 21:44:36 found io.delta#delta-core_2.12;1.0.0 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:38 found org.antlr#antlr4;4.7 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:39 found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.7 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:40 found org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:40 found org.antlr#ST4;4.0.8 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:40 found org.abego.treelayout#org.abego.treelayout.core;1.0.3 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:42 found org.glassfish#javax.json;1.0.4 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:43 found com.ibm.icu#icu4j;58.2 in central
2024-03-14 21:44:43 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/1.0.0/delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:44 [SUCCESSFUL ] io.delta#delta-core_2.12;1.0.0!delta-core_2.12.jar (1205ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:44 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.7/antlr4-4.7.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:44 [SUCCESSFUL ] org.antlr#antlr4;4.7!antlr4.jar (648ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:45 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7/antlr4-runtime-4.7.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:45 [SUCCESSFUL ] org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.7!antlr4-runtime.jar (323ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:45 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5.2/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:45 [SUCCESSFUL ] org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2!antlr-runtime.jar (239ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:45 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.8/ST4-4.0.8.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:45 [SUCCESSFUL ] org.antlr#ST4;4.0.8!ST4.jar (263ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:45 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/abego/treelayout/org.abego.treelayout.core/1.0.3/org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.3.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:45 [SUCCESSFUL ] org.abego.treelayout#org.abego.treelayout.core;1.0.3!org.abego.treelayout.core.jar(bundle) (198ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:46 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:46 [SUCCESSFUL ] org.glassfish#javax.json;1.0.4!javax.json.jar(bundle) (210ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:46 downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/58.2/icu4j-58.2.jar ...
2024-03-14 21:44:50 [SUCCESSFUL ] com.ibm.icu#icu4j;58.2!icu4j.jar (4085ms)
2024-03-14 21:44:50 :: resolution report :: resolve 8150ms :: artifacts dl 7179ms
```

please help!